# How to prevent react-query from fetching initially but enables refetching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-query, swr

I'm using `react-query v3.13` to fetch data from API.
What I want to do is to fetch API regularly from a certain point (for example, when clicking the start button), not from the time of calling useQuery.

I tried the following ways.

- set `enabled` property to `false` to disable automatic querying but it also disables re-fetching.
  I could not find a way to re-enable/set the `enabled` property to `true`. And I had to use `setTimeout` by myself to re-fetch regularly.
- keep `enabled` property as `true` but I could not find a way to disable the initial fetching.

Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: I remember there was the `forceFetchOnMount` property in the previous version, but it's replaced by `refetchOnMount` in version 3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you hardcode the `enabled` option to `false`, you can still use the `refetch` method you get back from `useQuery` to imperatively trigger a fetch. But the query will still be disabled, so no background updates.

if you want a lazy that is disabled, but enables when you call a function, the best way would be with a simple abstraction over useQuery with a local state:

```
const useLazyQuery = (key, fn, options) => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)
  return [() => setEnabled(true), useQuery(key, fn, { ...options, enabled })]
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do similar using `queryClient`?

Comment: I think you can have a disabled query and still do `queryClient.refetchQueries(key)` - this is similar to the `refetch` method returned from `useQuery`

Comment: Is there a way to prevent fetching when `refetch method` get called?

Answer (score -2):

```
import { useBoolean } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

function useLazyQuery(queryKey, {queryFn, onError}) {
  const [Enable, setEnable] = useBoolean(false);

  const Get = useQuery(queryKey, {
    queryFn,
    onError: typeof onError === "function" && onError,
    enabled: Enable, // Habilitar la consulta solo si el filtro no está vacío
  });

  return { ...Get, enable: setEnable.on, disable: setEnable.off };
}

export default useLazyQuery;
```